# Kubernetes - Typical multi-instance architecture

Tags: kubernetes

I am looking to deploy a SaaS app using Kubernetes to handle the scaling.  After much reading, I have come to the conclusion that multi-instance is the way to go.  Ideally, I will have a user log-in and when they have authenticated, a new instance (I suppose this is a pod) will be launched and in that pod they will find the data that they worked on previously. The data will be stored in a database, ideally a separate database for each user, but maybe just one large one.

Multi-instance is a good choice because the app will allow the user to launch a Python job that runs in the pod, so having isolation from other users is very important.

I have searched all over, but I can't find many examples of multi-instance implementations.  If anyone could point me to some good examples that would be great.

I imagine that I will have a separate pod running which will be the login page front end and then a simple back-end that will allow me to launch the pod.

But ... how do I tell the new pod which customer the pod is for and invoke the correct database?

Can I modify the pod template on the fly? and how do I pass the customer information, as an environment variable?

How then would I make sure I connect in the correct database for that customer?

Sorry if these are very basic questions.  The implementation will be small to start off with, but I want to do my best to ensure that I have chosen the correct architecture.

Thanks in advance for any help or comments.

Answer (score 0):

This makes sense, but with k8s it is easier to scale up multi-tenant apps just by replicating inter-exchangeable pods. It does not have the multi-instance logic by itself.

So you’d have to actually implement this application to handle auth, create deployments based on app templates, configure them via [environment variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/workload-resources/pod-v1/#environment-variables), assign them to users and manage their [persistent storage](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/).

We have similar requirements and even after 1.5 years you posted your question there’s not much publicly available on this topic. That’s why we have made public and open-source a small prototype of this “manager” app (shameless plug), it’s here: https://gitlab.com/simevo/juggler